# Spring Kafka error handling - v1.1.x

Tags: error-handling, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

How to deal with error handling in [spring-kafka](/questions/tagged/spring-kafka) version `1.1.x`?

[As I see it was introduced in version `2.0`...](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/a71054273cd3e9d0327fbf05da6bfff47b38e59b/src/reference/asciidoc/kafka.adoc#handling-exceptions)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In 1.x you can add an `ErrorHandler` implementation to the listener container (or container factory if you are using `@KafkaListener` annotations).

The 2.0 feature was added to make it easier to configure if you want a different error handler for each listener when using annotations.

Comment: thanks! will try to implement this, do you have such docs on github ?

Comment: It's mentioned (briefly) [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#_retrying_deliveries) and in [the javadocs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/config/ContainerProperties.html#setErrorHandler-org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler-).

Comment: @GaryRussell both the links have expired

Comment: Thanks; new links are [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#retrying-deliveries) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/AbstractMessageListenerContainer.html#setErrorHandler-org.springframework.kafka.listener.ErrorHandler-).

Comment: How do I get Consumer reference (nor ConsumerData) in my error handler? I am using Spring-kafka 1.3.2RELEASE. I need to commit offset manually for those which encountered error. I understand if I have Consumer refernce in ErrorHandler, then I can commit it. So I am looking for ways to have Consumer Reference in my ErrorHandler. Is it possible without changing Spring-Kafka version?

Comment: No; it's not possible with 1.x; 1.3.x will not be supported at all after this year so you should plan on upgrading anyway; the current version is 2.5.3. And, don't ask new questions in comments on old answers.